# overlapping of buttons in android

Tags: android, xml

I have two buttons in my XML file

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Now in my java code I want to enable 1st button and disable second on basis of some logic and some times vice-versa.
I have tried -

```
button1.setenabled(true);
button2.setenabled(false);
```

But in this case both the buttons are disabled as button1 mathces the parent and once it is disables teh button under it also gets disabled.
Please help how to handle such case.

Comment: Show how you defined buttons. Make shure you didn't do something like this: button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); - same id.

Comment: That is ok I alreday checked..   button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2)

Comment: from `XML` file it is look like that both buttons are on each other, at same position? Atm you are able to see only `button1` ? And no text on buttons and no background ?

Comment: @PankajKushwaha update your question every time when you want to add new information so you will get more answers.. btw you should post some java code for buttons in question so we can see where you going wrong?

Comment: @RDC : button1.setenabled(true);
button2.setenabled(false); This is the only relevant java code which I used and anyhow I have got the resolution that I have to bring the button to font using bringtofront()

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the top view does not let touch event pass to views beneath it. You will have to try some thing else to get this.

Can you please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys for your time. I found a solution.
I was disabling a button based on some conditions and enabling the other, but they were overlapping and the button on below of view was also getting disabled when i disabled the button on top of view, even though button on below was enabled.
I used-

```
button1.bringToFront();
```

And it is working fine now.

Thanks Chitranshu Asthana.. your answer hinted me